# How to use a custom Powershell module in a VSTS build task

Tags: powershell, module, azure-pipelines

I'm trying to set up VSTS build definitions that use custom Powershell scripts. I've created a BuildPackage.psm1 module file with two functions that I can use in two different build definitions. I'm trying to get one of these working, and have set up a task to import the module, followed by a task to run one of the functions.

I've copied my module into this location:

> .\src\Tools\PSModules\BuildFontPackage\BuildFontPackage.psm1

For the first task, to import the module, I've added a PowerShell Script task using the following inline script:

> $env:PSModulePath = "$env:BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY\src\Tools\PSModules;$env:PSModulePath"
>   Import-Module -Name BuildFontPackage.psm1

The Import-Module command runs and it appears to work: if I add the -Verbose parameter to Import-Module, I get the following:

> VERBOSE: Loading module from path 'C:\BA\47\s\src\Tools\PSModules\BuildFontPackage\BuildFontPackage.psm1'.
>   VERBOSE: Exporting function 'New-Package'.
>   VERBOSE: Exporting function 'New-AllPackages'.
>   VERBOSE: Importing function 'New-AllPackages'.
>   VERBOSE: Importing function 'New-Package'.

However, in the following task, when I try to use the New-Package function within the module, I get this error:

> New-Package : The term 'New-Package' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
>   Process completed with exit code 0 and had 1 error(s) written to the error stream.

It's as though my module isn't loaded.

How can I make this work?

Comment: `Get-Module -ListAvailable *` -- what is this returning ?

Comment: Each task starts with a clean context and previously loaded modules are not retained. If you have separate script tasks or separate inline script tasks you'll need to load your modules in each of these tasks.

Comment: In this case, it's simple enough to call the module in the same inline script / task that I use to import it. And if more complexity is involved, then all the complexity can be incorporated into modules that get loaded using a short inline script in the task definition.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are using private agent. So you can copy `BuildFontPackage\BuildFontPackage.psm1` into `$env:PSModulePath`. Then you can use the powershell module directly in VSTS build.

First, you can print the paths by executing `echo $env:PSModulePath` in your local machine (private agent). It will shows a list of paths as below:

```
C:\Users\username\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:
\windows\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\;c:\Program Files\Microsoft Security Client\MpPro
vider\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\PowerShell\Modules\;C:\Program Files\
AppFabric 1.1 for Windows Server\PowershellModules;C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012 R
2\Virtual Machine Manager\bin\psModules\;C:\Program Files\Microsoft System Center 2012 R2\Service 
Manager\PowerShell\;C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft S
DKs\Azure\PowerShell\ResourceManager\AzureResourceManager\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\A
zure\PowerShell\ServiceManagement\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\PowerShell\Storage\
```

Then copy `BuildFontPackage\BuildFontPackage.psm1` into any of the path in `$env:PSModulePath`.

Now you can build again, the powershell module should be recongnized by VSTS build.